# How do I preserve hyperreferences in the index when converting text from LaTex to HTML

Tags: hyperref, indexing, tex4ht, htlatex

I have written a book with three indexes in LaTex. I can produce a perfect hyperreferenced pdf file using the `dvipdf filename` command, but I cannot convert Latex into HTML using `htlatex` or `TEX4ht` without losing hyperlinks in the indexes. The program objects to index entries such as

```
\item Balzac, Honor\'{e}, 
        \hyperindexformat{\see{de Balzac, Honor\'{e}}}{53}.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6):

Run `'htlatex file'` which will give you `file.idx` among other files.

Given below are the commands to process the index file:

```
tex '\def\filename{{file}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht'
makeindex -o file.ind file.4dx
```

Run `'htlatex file'` again, now you will get `file.html` with hyperlinked index.

Comment: Windows users should read this answer from michal.h21: [tex4ht: hyperlink page numbers in the index](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162005).