# tex4ht: hyperlink page numbers in the index

Tags: indexing, tex4ht

This question was already answered by Radhakrishnan in an older post
 [How do I preserve hyperreferences in the index when converting text from LaTex to HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66974/how-do-i-preserve-hyperreferences-in-the-index-when-converting-text-from-latex-t), but I'm not able to get his solution to work. 
The .idx and .ind files are successfully generated. However, executing the following command in the dos console `tex '\def\filename{{test}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht'` gives me the error message

> This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
>   ! I can't find file `''.
>   
>                      \def
>   <*> '\def
>            \filename{{test}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht'
>   Please type another input file name:

Did I forget something? Any pointers to the cause of the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows command line doesn't use single quotes to quote arguments. You need to use double quotes instead:

```
tex "\def\filename{{test}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht"
```

Comment: life with Windows is always full of unexpected surprises :)

Comment: Sorry to ask, in which file I should keep this line "\def\filename{{test}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht", please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi sorry for the late reply. it is no longer necessary to use this. see https://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2020q1/002412.html for example.

Comment: Much thanks for your prompt reply.....